# Specify a particular machine name on slurm

Tags: bash, slurm

Hello does someone know how to specific on a slurm file which worker (machine) I want to use ?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the nodes that you would like to select with the --nodelist option:

```
sbatch --nodelist=myHosts[1-5,7] script.sh
```

More details are described [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html). 
A shorthand version of `--nodelist` is `-w`.

Comment: Thank you it works. Do you know if we can in contrary say I do not want this particular machine?

Comment: Yes, you can use`--exclude=<node name list>`. The shorthand for that option is `-x`.